# Physical consequences of non-trivial quantum states homology

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, topology

The set of quantum states of a finite dimensional system is a complex projective space, whose homology groups are non-trivial http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space#Homology.

Has this ever found any application in explaining/predicting some phenomena, or exploited in any way (maybe in quantum computing or quantum information)?